# Plone collection doesn't filter by third-party addon item type

Tags: collections, plone, plone-4.x

I'd like to use an old style collection (topic) in Plone, to show only a specific item type of a third party addon, but the collection remains empty.

Basically I use Products.Reflecto and would like to list all items of type "Reflecto file". I'm able to select the item type in the criteria tab of the collection, but the result doesn't show anything.
Are there some settings where I can define the indexing options of a collection, or something similar to get it?

Interestingly it's working with a new style collection, but I'm limited to the old one at the moment unfortunately.

Plone 4.3.1, Zope 2.13.20, Reflecto 3.0.6